# Google Doc Viewer shows “No Preview Available”

Tags: java, google-document-viewer

I'm using google document viewer to open my documents which are hosted in a Apache tomcat server. I've used this for several months and it worked pretty well. Now suddenly it gives me `No Preview Available` error even though all the files are in the same place. I didn't do any changes to the server.
The file has `0775` Permissions. What can be the problem?

File URL : [http://http://salestrackingsoftwaresrilanka.com/FILES/Article%201-%20Money%20Laundering.pdf](http://salestrackingsoftwaresrilanka.com/FILES/Article%201-%20Money%20Laundering.pdf)

URL with Google Doc Viewer :https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://salestrackingsoftwaresrilanka.com/FILES/Article%201-%20Money%20Laundering.pdf&embedded=true

Comment: Same here.  Must be a resurgence of a past bug or a new one with the same symptoms.  And Google is not very forthcoming about this stuff. -.-

Comment: @bought777 It happens when the file name has spaces. But earlier it worked even with the spaces

Comment: Also got biten by this. It used to work with spaces and other encoded chars but it stopped accepting them,

Comment: Same here this is so frustrating. I hope Google fixes this today.

Comment: They've fixed it it seems. Now it's finally working fine after 2 weeks